# throttleLast vs sample in RxJava

Tags: rx-java

Are there any difference between `throttleLast(long, TimeUnit)` and `sample(long, TimeUnit)` of Observable?

Both emit the last item of interval, so they are the same method to me.

If there are differences, what would be the better use case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the rx-java 1.0.x source code, it is the same thing, as throttleLast() is just calling sample():

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/v1.0.16/src/main/java/rx/Observable.java#L8819-L8821

Comment: It's still there in 1.1.7, though the file is too long and github truncates it. You can find it in raw view, if you Cmd+F for it: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/v1.1.7/src/main/java/rx/Observable.java

Comment: Thanks. I removed the mistaken line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I saw the source in 1.1.7 and I found that `throttlelast` just called `sample`.

Comment: same thing in rx2 :)